# Ckeditor Rails Sprocket Absolute Asset Path Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, sprockets

Using Ck editor Gem alongside with Active Admin I am not able to use the Browse Server functionality, I get the following error.

```
Asset names passed to helpers should not include the "/assets/" prefix. Instead of "/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/zip.gif", use "ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/zip.gif"
```

[image: Sprockets Path Error]

How can I configure the path of the Ckeditor assets in order for them to work with this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for Ckeditor is coming from ckeditor.rb

```ruby
  # Ckeditor files destination path
  mattr_accessor :relative_path
  @@relative_path = '/assets/ckeditor'
```

So this gem is not going to work fine with the latest versions of sprockets.
You can set sprockets-rails to 2.1.3 in your gem file

Comment: Thanks changing the gem was the solution :)

Comment: The good people from Ckeditor gem merged a pull request that fix this problem. Now you can update your Sprockets gem